# How to fit a 3d surface to data in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, 3d

I have a 10x16 table with 3d surface data in excel. I would like to fit this data to a surface where I can use this surface to calculate new points.

I made some VBA code that 2d interpolates but the above would suit me better and I cannot seem to make it happen.

Is there anyway to make this happen in excel? or can someone show me a software capable of doing this?

Pretty much posting this as a last result

---

This snippet doesn't run but is a representation of the data

```html
'       172.74 322.77 472.80 770.51 1068.23 1365.94 1803.76 2241.58 2679.40 3126.00 
10.67 1.6     1.776 1.96 2.24 4.132 5.12 5.756 7     8.2     9.4
15.33 1.6     1.772 1.96 2.272 4.012 5.156 5.52 7     8.2     9.4
18.67 1.6     1.836 2.044 2.58 4.024 5.036 5.4     7     8.2     9.4
27.67 1.6     1.848 2.088 2.64 3.796 4.708 5.948 7     8.2     9.4
32.00 1.6     1.824 2.088 2.62 3.8     4.512 5.832 7     8.2     9.4
37.00 1.6     1.836 2.152 2.54 3.996 4.556 5.02 7     8.2     9.4
46.67 1.6     1.832 2.14 2.648 3.884 4.62 4.796 7     8.2     9.4
51.67 1.6     1.892 2.1     2.692 3.54 4.876 5.312 6.836 8.2     9.4
60.00 1.6     1.872 2.076 2.748 3.688 4.66 5.768 6.932 8.404 9.6
68.33 1.6     1.864 2.064 2.712 3.62 4.744 5.552 7.016 8.384 9.69
76.67 1.6     1.888 2.152 2.736 3.536 4.716 5.656 6.568 8.336 9.7
83.33 1.6     1.864 2.16 2.7     3.716 4.708 5.4     6.508 8.352 9.90
91.67 1.6     1.896 2.216 2.756 3.584 4.42 5.52 6.472 8.488 9.97
100.00 1.6     1.744 2.036 2.808 3.708 4.356 5.672 6.728 8.42 10.
108.33 1.6     1.644 1.932 2.74 3.464 4.348 5.312 7.26 8.212 10.07
116.67 1.6     1.684 2.376 2.688 3.664 4.564 5.42 7.072 8.892 10.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can plot this data as a 3D-surface chart and it will look like this:

[image]

The rest of your question requires a LOT more detail about what you want to achieve. Don't just throw a concept into the ring. Edit your question and explain what you want to achieve, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

This answer will probably be downvoted because it is not an answer to your questions, but the requests for clarification was not suitable for a comment.

Over to you. Add a comment to your question when you've added the required detail.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I need to fit a surface to my data, i need a program or a way to fit a mathematical equation like  "z = x^2+y^3" to my data. Like you would do a curve fit in a 2d space.

Comment: You don't like to follow instructions, apparently. Your choice.